Issue with PDF forms - submit form doesn't work in SharePoint On-Prem 2019
We are using SharePoint 2019, the on-prem version.  We have a PDF that has a submit form button, but when the document is saved to a SharePoint document library, and opened from SharePoint, the submit form button doesn't work.  The document opens in the browser rather than Adobe Reader.
Is there a way to get the submit form button to work in SharePoint, when the document is launched in the browser?  I tried to adjust the library settings to open in the app, but that isn't working.
Thanks!

When you open a PDF document from a SharePoint document library in a browser, it typically defaults to opening in the browser itself rather than in Adobe Reader. This behavior can prevent certain functionalities, like the submit form button, from working as intended.
To resolve this issue, you can use Internet Explorer 11: This browser relies on ActiveX controls, which may allow the PDF to open in Adobe Reader directly, enabling the submit form functionality.
